Как получить доступ к камере
я знаю что есть Camera2/camerax api но есть ли какая либо библиотека с помощью которой можно написать такое приложение на которое ты отправляешь ссылку, которая запрашивает разрешение к доступу к камере и мы потом сможем подключаться к этой камере и смотреть что она снимает в данный момент

к какой камере? на андроиде?

@Эникейщик да на андроид
